# Partition windows does not exit

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

Why does the 500GB HDD appear here while in Other Locations it's not coming out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you run Ubuntu with an USB stick or where did you install Ubuntu? or did you have installed Windows and Ubuntu on the 240GB SSD? or if you are only interested in the 500GB hard disk and why its not showed up in the filemanager, did you see this drive in Windows?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Did Windows come with Bitlocker setup?

Answer (score 0):

It simply seems the 500 GB disk is formatted with a filesystem and/or encryption that Ubuntu does not recognize.

So disk manager can see there is a partition, but the contents are not accessible from Ubuntu.